# Storing tables within a record in a database

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I'm thinking of creating something to help with finances or the like just as a little project to help my web development skills, but there's one thing that I can' get my head around in the planning stage.

Say I have multiple users, each user would be shown a table with each week/month and the expenditure, tax, etc for them. How would I store that in a database? Would I be able to embed some sort of table within a record, or would I have to use a many-to-many relation?

If anyone knows a good solution, I would love to hear it!

Answer (score 3):

From the little you described your Expenditure table would be in a many to one relationship to your Person table. Each row in the expenditure table could hold a Date field as well as other information about the expenditure.  The only reason you would need a many to many relationship is if many people were linked to a single expenditure. You probably want to read a good book on data modeling.

Answer (score 2):

I would have a user table (id, user_name, password, email...) and a finance table (id, user_id, date, transaction, amount, detail...), the single finance table would be responsible for both income and outgoings simply by +/- amount. This is a one to many relationship (one user has many finance records) then you would query roughly like

```
SELECT * FROM tblFinance WHERE user_id = foo AND date BETWEEN NOW()-7 AND NOW()
```

You can of course aggregate etc in your queries, hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You would not embed a table. You are confusing between how the data is stored and how it is displayed.

Assuming you are using a relational database, you would store the data in a number of database tables. For example, you could have a database table with the following columns (oversimplified for explanation)

```
userid, expense_type, expense_description, amount, date_of_expenditure
```

This table will then store the expenses for all users.

Now for displaying on the webpage, your application would fetch the data from your database tables and render it on the web page. How you display it is based on your requirements. Your application will be responsible for collating, aggregating, filtering the data fetched from the database before showing it to the user.